# YiiChat extension is not working in my yii app

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i installed yiichat extention in my yii app, and I followed as per the documentation  https://bitbucket.org/christiansalazarh/yiichat. when I finished the documentation and viewed it in a browser the chat textarea’s attribute is disabled ( a disabled icon is showing when mouse hover the field) is there any other configurations i want to add ? I am not able to send message in the chat app !please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

did you review the jQuery version ? please use Yii 13 and clean your assets. after that test it again.